# Issue with multiple Volley requests

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Whenever I want to perform Volley request based on user input I must press button twice to instead of click the button only one time to get the requested response.

I Used wait() function, but still have the same problem and application corrupted, while I expected the application work normally.

This is what I have reached to until now:

```
   String URL="https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_countries&APIkey=b4c74bf2fcf3937f783b752649018a42a3b1bde9d5d7c03ff36f61fc06c00c77";
        RequestQueue rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonArrayRequest objreq= new JsonArrayRequest(

                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {

                            Log.e("result:",response.get(0).toString());
                            JSONObject obj;
                            for (int count = 0; count < response.length(); count++) {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(count);
                                String name = obj.getString("country_name");
                                Log.e("Country:",name);
                                send(name,true);
                                //  Team t=new Team(2,"mki");
                                //x.insertTeam(t);
                                //so on
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("rest response",error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );
        rq.add(objreq);

        btn_send_message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ChatModel model;
public void onClick(View v) {
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
else if(text.contains("result"))
                {
                    ChatModel model = new ChatModel(text, true); // user send message
                    list_chat.add(model);

                    String result="";
                    String head2Head;
                    String input[] = text.split(" ");
                    String[] arr=null ;
                    DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(x);
                    try{
                        result=dbAdapter.getResultfromDB("Bristol City","Reading");

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        result="error";
                    }

                    if(result.equals("error")==true) {

                        APIAdapter ap = new APIAdapter();
                        head2Head = ap.getResult("Bristol City", "Reading", "kjkn", getApplicationContext());
                        finres = head2Head;
                        Log.e("headto",head2Head);
                        arr = head2Head.split("\n");
                        }
                    model = new ChatModel("First team:"+arr[0]+"\nSecond team:"+arr[1]+"\n"+"Date:"+arr[2], false);
                    list_chat.add(model);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I do understand your question. The thing that is happening is the data is taking its time to be loaded. So use something like a progress bar and change its visibility inside `Response.Listener` and `Response.ErrorListener`. To make this work properly move the line `rq.add(objreq);` inside `onClickListener` and before this line change the visibility of the progress bar to visible.

**Example**

*Layout.xml*

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mainParentRel"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="@drawable/grad_bg_2"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbars="vertical">

         <!-- You can use any thing here
              Put all your previous buttons edittext etc here.
              You can replace the scrollview with any layout
              Or You can completely remove the scrollview and 
              directly put your views here. -->

        </ScrollView>

        <!-- This is the progress bar layout. Always remember to set its visibility to GONE.-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/progressRelLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/company_logo_progress"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/company_logo"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/company_logo" />
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/company_logo_progress"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:theme="@style/WhiteAccent"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar"
                android:text="Loading..."
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

*Example.java*

```java
RelativeLayout progressRL; 
//Inside onCreate()
progressRL= findViewById(R.id.progressRelLayout);

//Do rest of your stuff
   String URL="https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_countries&APIkey=b4c74bf2fcf3937f783b752649018a42a3b1bde9d5d7c03ff36f61fc06c00c77";
        RequestQueue rq= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonArrayRequest objreq= new JsonArrayRequest(

                Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
progressRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        try {

                            Log.e("result:",response.get(0).toString());
                            JSONObject obj;
                            for (int count = 0; count < response.length(); count++) {
                                obj = response.getJSONObject(count);
                                String name = obj.getString("country_name");
                                Log.e("Country:",name);
                                send(name,true);
                                //  Team t=new Team(2,"mki");
                                //x.insertTeam(t);
                                //so on
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
progressRL.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        Log.e("rest response",error.toString());
                    }
                }
        );


        btn_send_message.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            ChatModel model;
public void onClick(View v) {

rq.add(objreq);
progressRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                String text = editText.getText().toString();
else if(text.contains("result"))
                {
                    ChatModel model = new ChatModel(text, true); // user send message
                    list_chat.add(model);

                    String result="";
                    String head2Head;
                    String input[] = text.split(" ");
                    String[] arr=null ;
                    DBAdapter dbAdapter=new DBAdapter(x);
                    try{
                        result=dbAdapter.getResultfromDB("Bristol City","Reading");

                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        result="error";
                    }

                    if(result.equals("error")==true) {

                        APIAdapter ap = new APIAdapter();
                        head2Head = ap.getResult("Bristol City", "Reading", "kjkn", getApplicationContext());
                        finres = head2Head;
                        Log.e("headto",head2Head);
                        arr = head2Head.split("\n");
                        }
                    model = new ChatModel("First team:"+arr[0]+"\nSecond team:"+arr[1]+"\n"+"Date:"+arr[2], false);
                    list_chat.add(model);
                }
}
```

After doing this it might cause errors. Just move the things that will change after loading of data inside `Response.Listener`.

Comment: No this is not my issue, let me explain with example, here I want to connect to an API that have information about football matches(results, statistics..... etc) if the user want to ask for example about (result of Bristol City Vs Reading) then click send button the chatbot should replys to user with "result and the date of match" , actually this is not happen the answer shows after 2 clicks for the button not 1 click, how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: It might be also caused because the views doesn't know if the data is changed. So move any textView/Recyclerview/anyview that loads data from the internet inside the `Response.Listener`